# CSS menu wrapper overflowing on iphone screen

Tags: html, ios, css

I have a website, please see: [Death Valley](http://www.deathvalleyillustration.org)

In my various browsers the site is looking ok. However, on IOS devices there seems to be some sort of overflow from the menu wrapper. This is my guess. There may be something else causing it. It is a black large box at the top right hand side of the screen. Please view the site on an apple device to see what I mean. My CSS and html are below. Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #000000;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 13.5px;
    color: #8A8985;
}

#wrapper {
    overflow: visible;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.container  {
    width: 1200px;
    min-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    device-width:100%;
    overflow: visible;
}

#header-wrapper {
    overflow: visible;
    height: 600px;
    device-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}

#header {
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
    Overflow: visible;
    Position: relative; 
}

#logo {
    overflow: visible;
    height: 150px;
    float: center;
}

#menu-wrapper {
    overflow: visible; 
    height: 52px;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    background: #000000;
    Position: relative; 
    Margin: 0 auto;
    Padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
}

#menu {
    overflow: hidden; 
    height: 52px; 
}

#menu ul  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
    text-align: center;
    Position: relative; 
}

#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: center;
    Position: relative; 
}

#menu a {
    display: inline-block;
    float: center;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    line-height: 52px;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, Ariel;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#menu a:hover, #menu .current_page_item a {
    background: #CCFF00;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

#page {
    overflow: visible;
    width: 1200px;
    float: center;
}

#column1 {
    float: left;
    width: 384px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#column2 {
    float: left;
    width: 384px;
}

#column3 {
    float: right;
    width: 384px;
}

.box1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 200px;
    background: url(images/img04.jpg) no-repeat center bottom;
}
```

Here is the HTML up to that point:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu-wrapper">
        <div id="menu" class="container">
            <Center>
                <ul>
                    <li class="current_page_item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Animation.html">Animation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </Center>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="logo" class="container">
        <Center>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="images/Logo.gif" width="474" height="150" alt="Death Valley Illustration Logo" />
                <Center/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="page" class="container">
            <Center>
                <a href="mailto:gavin@deathvalleyillustration.org?subject=I want to pay you money" class="button">Email Me!</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/deathvalley_" class="button">Follow me!</a>
                <div class="entry">
                    <p>
                        Welcome to <b> Death Valley Illustration. </b> </br>  You can browse all of my recent designs & commissions by scrolling down the page and clicking on any of the images in the projects section below.</br>
                        Please get in touch if you have any potential collaborations or freelance illustration work that you would like to discuss.
                    </p>
                <Center> 
            <HR>    
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a set width so do that in the body-

```
body {min-width: 1200px;}
```